# Is it possible to configure EF Core to not throw error if model does not match database?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Our database evolution rate is getting more and more, and we can't migrate to NoSQL at this time.

The problem with EF Core is that any column that is renamed, or removed, would break everything. The entire context breaks for that change.

Can EF Core be configured to be tolerant for mismatching model and table?

Comment: It is hard to imagine how an application should work correctly if not all of the properties can be read from or saved to the DB.

Comment: It's not about working 100%. It's about partial failure. At least it can show the products until developers get time to solve the issue. At least it can save `contact us` forms. But it fails altogether, why? because `FullName` is changed to `DisplayName`.

Comment: then maybe do not rename the column? instead, create backwards compatible migrations?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov, yes, you're right. But as I said in the beginning, the database evolution rate is high. We can't afford to create migration scripts for all of the changes. Either we should move to NoSQL, or we should configure EF to be more tolerant.

Comment: It is not possible. EF Core generates SQL without accessing to database. And it generates SQL for all know columns of the entity.

Comment: why do you need renames? "FullName" to "DisplayName" makes almost no sense to me. business logic may be updated instead - property may have ColumnAttribute if you don't like it's name in C#. deletion as well - just don't delete the columns that are not removed from c# entities yet. This sounds like not like a SQL/NoSQL/EF issue, but a management & communication fault

Comment: You need to fix your development processes.  

Even if you could make EF Core tolerant of model discrepancies, you'd just run into data quality problems.  Personally I'd rather have the system error than discover months later that all my data is broken because an error was silenced.